# Импорт *.ovpn файла в network-manager-openvpn-gnome

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

Приобрел в пользование VPN, продавец дал настройки в виде одного файла .ovpn

Внутри файл выглядит так

```
remote ***.***.***.*** 443 tcp-client

remote-random

dev tun
nobind

persist-tun
persist-key
key-direction 1
tls-client
ns-cert-type server
topology subnet
socket-flags TCP_NODELAY
comp-lzo
auth SHA1
cipher AES-256-CBC
keysize 256
verb 3
mute-replay-warnings
keepalive 5 40
pull
route-metric 2
#setenv opt block-outside-dns


<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>

<key>
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>

<tls-auth>
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
...
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

Ошибка выглядит так

[image: Ошибка]

При этом `openvpn --config de.ovpn` все отлично подключается. Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот [здесь](https://askubuntu.com/a/816140/416190) рекомендуют «разложить» команду `remote` на отдельные составляющие. т.е., заменить строку:

```
remote ***.***.***.*** 443 tcp-client
```

на

```
remote ***.***.***.***
port 443
proto tcp-client
```

Comment: Робит! Благодарствую =)